# How do I fix not null constraints error on flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I have an db which has two table: note and category. There is a schema below for my tables. I want to insert a record to the note table but I'm getting this error below. Can anyone please help?
[image]

Here is the method I create for insert a record to note table and the error which I'm getting from this process.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly states that you declared your `category_id` as `NOT NULL` but you are passing a null value while trying to insert a note.

There may be 2 approach here,

1. You can simply remove NOT NULL constraint from your table definition by modifiying `"category_id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1` to `"category_id" INTEGER DEFAULT 1`
2. You should really be sure that you are passing a non-null value to `category_id` in `insert` operation

As I see from your logs, it clearly says that one of the argument you are passing is null and it causes this crash.

Hope these helps you to detect your problem and fix it.